# Kernel panic when trying to boot Ubuntu 20.04 on HP Z400

Tags: 20.04, hp

I saw some related questions online. I have bios v3.20 on my Xeon w3550 16gb hp z400. It has windows 10 pro installed on an ssd 240gb intel and has another 1tb hdd.

I tried booting up from usb and dvd ubuntu mate 20.04 64 bit but in both cases it have me kernel panic.
I removed the ssd containing windows. The same result.

Surprise, lubuntu 16.04 i386 32bit worked with

- In the setup menu navigate to Advanced -> Device Options. Make sure that "SATA RAID Option ROM Download" is disabled if this item is available.
- In the setup menu navigate to Storage -> Storage Options. Make sure that "IDE" is selected.

just like in the 2nd answer from here:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2445471

Funny thing is that now even if I revert the above settings and reconnect the ssd, the windows won't boot.

**Update**

Ubuntu Mate 18.04.1 64bit fails as well.

Ubuntu 16.04.3 i386 32 bit works with the above settings reverted

Ubuntu Mate 18.04.1 32 bit does not work

Comment: Rverting those changes, if the only ones you did, would make Windows boot again. I suspected that other settings were change, namely from UEFI to Legacy or vice-versa. Please note both Windows and Ubuntu *should* be installed preferably in UEFI mode but if the already installed Windows is in Legacy mode the second OS must be in the same mode. Also you need to install AHCI support in Windows before changing drive modes and yes, it's something you must do - AHCI - be cause "RAID" or "Intel RST" modes aren't compatible (yet) with Linux distros. And update UEFI before anything else (...)

Comment: (...) no 32-bit OS should be used, obviously, and particularly not Lubuntu 16.04 that's out of support already (since 2019 for the desktop; since now for everything else). The 32-bit architecture is no longer supported, at all, by Ubuntu.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I know I should not use 16.04, but I had the dvds and I tried. The goal is Ubuntu not Windows here.

Comment: So, if not dual-booting, just make all the aforementioned changes and install Ubuntu.

Comment: I deleted all partitions from both drives using gparted from ubuntu 16.04 that works. I tried installing ubuntu mate 20.04 with the mentioned settings and with them reverted. All I get is the try or install ubuntu screen, and if I click on try, it ends with kernel panic. I have non-RAID disks if I look with raid enabled and ctrl+i.

Comment: Possibly I was wrong assuming this was an early UEFI. Instead, it's probably late BIOS. Either way, whichever the firmware is start by installing the latest version available. This will automatically load the factory defaults but even so, if needed, disable RAID, etc. And depending on the graphics you may need to boot with `nomodeset`.

Comment: How can I install latest ubuntu when it does not work? :) nomodeset can be set from grub or terminal. I don't have that yet. EDIT. you mean latest bio version?

Comment: Updating BIOS or UEFI generally is OS agnostic and most don't even require an OS installed (directly from settings with the file in the root of a normal USB stick or with a FreeDOS bootable USB stick) and when not the case, Windows is needed, not Linux (update is a Windows exe file). `nomodeset` is to be added to the boot of the installation media, usually by editing ("e") the "Try Ubuntu" menu option.

Comment: https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-z400-workstation/3718668 but it may change nothing. This reddit suggests ACPI issues so other boot parameters are likely to be needed. I would try also `acpi=off`: https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/a9fwy2/hp_z400_live_boot_issues_kernel_panic/

Comment: I updated bios from 3.20 to 3.61 and with emulation IDE and SATA RAID Option ROM Download disabled it checks the disck. If it works I'll put a complete answer here. Thanks.

Comment: Does anyone know if hp z400 can be used in dualboot mode, taking into account that it has different bios for linux vs windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of @ChanganAuto I managed to install Ubuntu mate 20.04:

1. I made the bios changes from my question
2. After this only ubuntu 16.04 32 bit was able to load in order for me to delete all partitions from the drives, including Windows, with GParted. (if anyone has the same problem and wants to dual boot with Windows, skip this part and see what happens)
3. I updated bios from 3.20 to 3.61.

The kernel panic was gone and I installed Ubuntu.
After installation I reverted the changes from my questions to RAID+AHCI internal only and enabled RAID ROM Download.

Edit. I made another hp z400 bios update from 3.15 to 3.61 for ubuntu and just now I realized that hp z400 has different bios for windows and linux.